# Probabily of profit after n attempts in a game of chance

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a game of chance where the probabily of winning is $1/3$ that the cost of playing is $1$ point, and in case of winning the earning is $2$ points, I am trying to find a mathamtical expression (as simple as possible) that expresses the probabily of not being at a loss after $n$ attempts.

To put it more simply, what are the chances that after $n$ games the points I'll have will be equal or greater than the points I had before I started playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for each time you play you are at a net profit of 1 for winning and a net loss of 1 for losing, you see that you have a total profit of a non-negative amount if $\#wins\geq \#losses$, which in turn implies that $\#wins\geq \frac{n}{2}$

We can describe this with a binomial distribution.  Let winning constitute a "success", $n$ be the number of trials, $X$ be the random variable counting the number of successes, and $p$ be the probability of success.

> Binomial distribution:  $P(X=r) = \binom{n}{r}p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$

Here, we are interested in $P(X\geq \frac{n}{2})$, i.e. the probability that we won at least half of the time.

We get then $Pr(X\geq \frac{n}{2}) = \sum\limits_{i=\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil}^n\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^i$

Note, we can use this same problem setup for other scenarios, such as when you "win 3 points" for winning.  What will change is the starting point for the indexing variable.  For example, if you win 3 points in a success, and the gamecost is still 1, it implies the net profit of a win is 2 and net loss of a lose is 1 (a gain of negative 1).  That implies that to not be at an overall net loss, that $2\#wins\geq \#losses$, and so $3\#wins\geq \#losses+\#wins = n$ and that $\#wins\geq \frac{n}{3}$, and so you will use $\lceil\frac{n}{3}\rceil$ as the starting point of the summation.

---

For your specific example, with $n=5$ and $p=\frac{1}{3}$ you get:

$Pr(\text{having a nonnegative number of points})=Pr(X\geq 2.5) = \binom{5}{3}(\frac{1}{3})^3(\frac{2}{3})^2 + \binom{5}{4}(\frac{1}{3})^4(\frac{2}{3})^1 + \binom{5}{5}(\frac{1}{3})^5(\frac{2}{3})^0 = \frac{10\cdot 4  +  5\cdot 2  +  1}{3^5} = \frac{51}{243}=\frac{17}{81}$

To show equivalence with the other answerer's method, setting $n=4$ and $p=\frac{1}{3}$ you get:

$Pr(X\geq 2)=\binom{4}{2}(\frac{1}{3})^2(\frac{2}{3})^2 + \binom{4}{3}(\frac{1}{3})^3(\frac{2}{3})^1 + \binom{4}{4}(\frac{1}{3})^4(\frac{2}{3})^0 = \frac{6\cdot 4 + 4\cdot 2 + 1}{3^4} = \frac{24+8+1}{81}=\frac{33}{81} = \frac{11}{27}$

noting further that the different "interpretations" amounted to either us starting our indices at $\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil$ or $\lceil \frac{n}{3}\rceil$, which in the case of $n=4$ both coincided to be $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is to use generating functions.  I'm not sure how to interpret your terms, so I'll offer two possibilities, and one of them is likely to be what you want.

The first interpretation is that it costs one point to play, and you have a $1/3$ chance of winning two points, *plus* the one point you wagered (so you net two points).  In that case, the generating function for a single round is

$$
F(z) = \Bigl(\frac{2}{3z}+\frac{z^2}{3}\Bigr)
$$

To determine the probability that you are up after $n$ rounds, you simply evaluate $[F(z)]^n$ and add up the coefficients on the terms with degree greater than zero (greater than or equal to zero if you want the probability you are either tied or up).  For instance, for $n = 4$, we have

$$
[F(z)]^4 = \frac{z^8}{81} + \frac{8z^5}{81} + \frac{24z^2}{81}
         + \frac{32}{81z} + \frac{16}{81z^4}
$$

so the probability you are up (you cannot be tied, as there is no constant term) is $(1+8+24)/81 = 11/27$.

The other interpretation is that it costs one point to play, and you have a $1/3$ chance of winning two points, *including* the one point you wagered (so you net only one point).  In that case, the generating function for a single round is

$$
F(z) = \Bigl(\frac{2}{3z}+\frac{z}{3}\Bigr)
$$

and you proceed along the same lines.  Again, for $n = 4$, you would have

$$
[F(z)]^4 = \frac{z^4}{81} + \frac{8z^2}{81} + \frac{24}{81}
         + \frac{32}{81z^2} + \frac{16}{81z^4}
$$

which has the same coefficients as before (unsurprisingly), but different powers.  Now, the probability that you are strictly up is only $(1+8)/81 = 1/9$, and the probability that you are up or tied is $(1+8+24)/81 = 11/27$.

Comment: Can you add an explanation (or link to an existing one) on how you created the generating function and chosed the coefficients? (It's just that it has been a little over a year since I last used them and I don't remember how they work)

Comment: Sure.  If you have a discrete random variable $X$ that takes on only integer values, then the generating function is $F(z) = E(z^X) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty z^k P(X=k)$.  The nice thing about the generating function is that if you have $n$ independent random variables, the generating function of their sum is the product of their generating functions.  That's what we applied, above.